# Design Advice: Parsing lines of text and dumping certain fields and assign to "buckets" - LINQ, RegEx,

Tags: c#, regex, linq, parsing, lambda

I am seeking some advice on how best to tackle the following scenario:

There are these text files that contain certain metadata about accidents from the city. The majority of the contents of these text files are dumped into a database. The main piece, i.e. body, of the text files are entered into this one field, say `ReportBody`, in the `Accidents` table.

I have to read/parse this one column's contents into specific fields depending on what is being parsed. For example, here is a typical line from the text file that is entered into the `ReportBody` field in the database:

"Report for Mar 11, 2014 at 19:23 a traffic incident was submitted by officer - Badge 8394 Speeding through school zone - Employee ID:FOWSL, xxx, yyy"

In general, all of these "reports" follow this format:

"Report for [`Date`] at [`Time`] a [`Incident_Type]` incident was submitted by officer - [`Badge_Number`] [`Category`] - Employee ID:[`ID_Number`], [`other_Property1`], [`other_Property2`]"

where everything within the brackets are things I am collecting into an `Accident` class and submitting the Collection of `Accidents` into the database. Everything not enclosed within a bracket, then I am thinking I can use those strings as reference points that I have to collect something near by, e.g. I know that every time I come across the string "by officer - ", I will be assigning that [Badge_Number] string into the setter of the `Accident` class. Same logic with when I come across " - Employee ID:", I know I need to extract what is between the ":" and the first white space after that, " ", which in this case is the `Accident`'s `EmployeeId` property.

It's been about two years since I worked heavily with `LINQ`, but recall I was able to do some heavy parsing and thought it was just elegant. Looking at it now, not sure what is the best path since I've been working in another framework and not sure if `Lambdas`, `Predicates`, `RegEx`, or so on is the best viable path.

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: LinQ is not about parsing texts. I think your best bet is RegEx.

Comment: @nvoigt: LINQ just seems so much more natural when dealing with OOP concepts like objects and collections. I would be able to harness the huge flexibility these concepts afford compared to RegEx, which I feel is suited for "parsing text", which I feel my case is more complicated (I think). Thanks for your comment.